# Unable to use .accdb as a datasource for report builder even though connection test is successful

Tags: odbc, connection-string, reportbuilder

I am trying to set up an .accdb as a datasource on the reporting server. The database is local on the server and I have followed all the instructions to create a 32 bit and a 64 bit ODBC connection for .mdb and .accdb. I set up the data source on the Report Manager site as ODBC with dsn=dbname and test the connection and it is successful.

From the Report Manager site, I open a report in Report Builder. I add a dataset and point to the shared connection. Test connection is successful.

I create a new data set based on this data source and click Query Designer and get this error: Unable to Connect to Datasource dbname. ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application.

Then I prompted for credentials. Of course nothing works there. And this particular .accdb has only Admin with no password anyway. All users can access it.

The error makes me think there's a 32 bit vs 64 bit conflict. The .accdb is 32 bit, but Report Manager only sees it with the 64 bit connection, then tanks when I try to create the data set.

I've set the same odbc connections up on my local machine and on the server. Still no dice. Any and all help would be appreciated.

---

I kept working on this and was able to create a data source with the following connection string:

Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=\server\path\database.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;

I edited the report and used query builder to test the query and results. Query builder allows me to see results. Yay! Progress!

But now when I preview/run the report I get the following:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'dataset1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work. I had to install the 32 and 64 bit drivers on both the reporting server and the local (editing) machine. I created identical DSNs (32 bit and 64 bit) on each machine. Then set up the datasource with an OLE DB connection string.

Once complete, I was able to write reports against the database (but not browse tables). Other users could access the report from their own machines without the ODBC connections or drivers installed.

We'll call this a win. On to the next problem.